# How to load compiled library in an R package

Tags: r, package, cran

I am writing an R package where I need to include a compiled library file qserver.dll and dym.load it when the package is loaded in R throught library(myPackage). This qserver.dll is provided by a third party vendor so I don't have the source code.

I did some research on the internet but information is rare. What I have found so far is that I should put this file in the to inst/ subdirectory of my package folder. However, how I can determine the path to this file when writing the package so I can write something like

```
dyn.load("path/to/file/qserver.dll")
```

when writing the package. Thanks very much.

Comment: if you eventually made `qserver` into an R package format, would you mind to share? I was actually thinking of converting it to a package myself as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Items in the `inst` directory of a package are made available through

```
system.file(..., package=<mypkg>)
```

so assuming you had that `.dll` in a package path `<pkg>/inst/lib/qserver.dll`, you can do

```
system.file("lib/qserver.dll", package=<mypkg>)
```

to get the file location.

Now, of course, this is not CRAN acceptable, and the [CRAN Repository Policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) is quite clear on this. So if you really need `qserver.dll`, either you need to find the source code, or consider a different route for distribution.

Comment: Actually source is available in [code.kx.com repo, e.g. for w64 here](http://code.kx.com/wsvn/code/cookbook_code/r/w64_qserver/), namely files `base.c` and `c.o`. Instructions how to build `qserver.dll` from the provided source is in `README.txt`. Not sure if that will work as is, haven't tested.

Comment: Also would check licencing of the `qserver` utility before posting anything to CRAN, as kdb is a proprietary database.