# Include and use precompiled .dll / .so in R package

Tags: r, dll, r-package

I would like to create an R package that contains a precompiled .dll/.so file. It is unclear to me where to put the file in the package structure (e.g. in the folder inst?) and how to load it -- e.g. what lines do I need to add to other files that allow the .dll or .so to be loaded and functions contained in it to be used.

In particular, I would like to see some examples for the use of `dyn.load()`, `.C()` and `library.dynam()`.
In a normal script that is not a package, I would load the dll via

```
dyn.load("path/to/my_dll.dll")
```

and then call specific functions contained in that .dll by using

```
.C("dll_func", input)
```

However, this seems to be different when trying to convert my script into a package. 
Also, do I need `.onLoad` and how do I use it correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load compiled library in an R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715127/how-to-load-compiled-library-in-an-r-package). tl;dr : put `my_dll.dll` in `inst/lib/` and try `dyn.load(system.file("lib/my_dll.dll", package=<mypkg>))`

Comment: Nothing about the `onLoad` in the linked post...

Comment: Volokh:see [here](https://github.com/stla/dir2json/blob/master/R/zzz.R) for an example of `onLoad`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Indeed there was some helpful information in the question you linked, however there are still some difficulties.
I use an R package with Rcpp and it automatically generates a file `RcppExports.cpp` (generated by `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`) that includes references to functions contained in the precompiled .dll file. Unfortunately, as soon as this file is generated by building the package, a further `devtools::check()` gives an error:
`RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.rdata+0x760): undefined reference to dll_func.` Is there any way around this?